# CSS checked not working

Tags: html, css, mvc-editor-templates

HTML Element:

```
<p> <input type="button"> id="edit" value="edit page" /> </p>
```

This div has been hidden with display:none , I want to toggle the visibility to display:normal.

```
@Html.EditorFor(
    modelItem => model.user, 
    new {
        htmlAttributes = new {
            @ class = "user" 
        } 
    } 
)
```

The class 'user' has the following properties:

```
.user {
    width:200px;
    margin-left:3px;
    display:none;
}
```

For some reason my checked CSS isn't working:

```
#edit:hover + user {
    color:black;
}

#edit:checked + user {
    display:normal;
}
```

JSFiddle Example : https://jsfiddle.net/gp7pyssu/

I don't want to use any Javascript to toggle visibility, I'd like it to be done in pure CSS3.

Comment: #edit:checked + user {
display:normal;
}   This is not valid one,

Comment: Hi @Aqib welcome to StackOverflow. It appears the HTML you have posted is not valid, it appears you have an extra ">" between the type and id attributes. Also, can you post any javascript you already have tried for this, that will help us all answer the question more clearly.

Comment: The extra ">" isn't in the code , I typed this out and made this mistake and I haven't attempted any Javascript , as I wish to have this based on CSS3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several CSS issues here:

### display value

In CSS, there is no `normal` value for `display`.

Use `block`, `inline` or another value that fits your needs : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display

### + selector

To use the + selector in your CSS, you have to have your `div` just after your `input`, so you have to remove the `p` surrounding the `input`: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/adjacent

### :checked selector

The selector `:checked` is only available for `radio` and `checkbox` `input`, you can't use it with a `button` `input`: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:checked

---

With all that, you can check this [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xq0cL7jb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p> <input type="button" id="edit" value="edit page" /> </p>

#edit:checked + user {
display:block;
}
```

Have a look

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.